# Python: Loop: formatting string

Tags: python

I don't know how to express this. I want to print:

`_1__2__3__4_`

With `"_%s_"` as a substring of that. How to get the main string when I format the substring? (as a shortcut of:

```
for x in range(1,5):
    print "_%s_" % (x)
```

(Even though this prints multiple lines))

Edit: just in one line

Comment: Do you mean something like `"_" + s + "_"`

Comment: I think something like this is exactly what he's looking for... Just adding a string onto another in every loop iteration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you mean something like this?

```
 my_string = "".join(["_%d_" % i for i in xrange(1,5)])
```

That creates a list of the substrings as requested and then concatenates the items in the list using the empty string as separator (See [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) documentation).

Alternatively you can add to a string though a loop with the `+=` operator although it is much slower and less efficient:

```
s = ""
for x in range(1,5):
    s += "_%d_" % x
print s
```

Comment: Yeah! I exactly saw that: `"_%s_" % i for i in range(1,5)`. Why do u use join to empty string?

Comment: @wonderwhy `join` is a method on the `str` type - so you have to use it on *some* string. It's often used like `', '.join(items)` -> `foo, bar, baz` as a very elegant way to deal with the [fencepost problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error), but just as well can be used with the empty string for easy way to concatenate items of a sequence.

Comment: Ah yea, I tried without join to "" and it just gave an array. Anyway the logic I saw some time ago and I was looking forward to seeing is that.

Comment: @LukasGraf hmm, I didn't know about the fencepost stuff till now, that's interesting. I didn't realize about that if I hadn't got that error :) Cool method.

Answer (score 2):

```
print("_" + "__".join(map(str, xrange(1,5)))) +"_"
_1__2__3__4_




In [9]: timeit ("_" + "__".join(map(str,xrange(1,5)))) +"_"

1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.38 µs per loop


In [10]: timeit "".join(["_%d_" % i for i in xrange(1,5)])
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.19 µs per loop
```

Comment: This works great, but I was looking for the logic @PaulSeeb is showing in his first example, since he formats the string inside a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3:

```
print("_{}_".format("__".join(map(str,range(1,5)))))
_1__2__3__4_
```

Python 2:

```
print "_{0}_".format("__".join(map(str,range(1,5))))
_1__2__3__4_
```

Comment: this is an alternative to paul seed's answer. Very interesting too.

Answer (score 1):

you can maintain your style if you want to.

if you are using python 2.7:

```
from __future__ import print_function
for x in range(1,5):
    print("_%s_" % (x), sep = '', end = '')
print()
```

for python 3.x, import is not required.

python doc: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print

Comment: That's a cool answer, I didn't know about that way to push to queue and then print altogether. That's not what I was looking for but is a very interesting answer. Thanks for sharing that.